# Ubuntu Studio 14.04 - USB Soundcard

Tags: soundcard

I am a new Ubuntu Studio 14.04 user and would like to have a compatible USB sound card. I've seen Focusrite 2i2 compatibility but does anyone have experience about Focusrite Scarlet Solo, which is a smaller version? Thanks..